# Magento 2 - how to add action logging?

Tags: logging, magento2

Does anybody know how I can add an action to the `Action Log - Report` in the enterprise edition?

My assumption is to using plugins but I don't figure out how. I want to track when the method `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry::updateStockItemBySku` is called.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean when say "add an action"? What do you want do?

Comment: I want to track when the method `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry::updateStockItemBySku` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You should read article in documentation [Magento plug-ins](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Step by step how to create plug-in to `\Magento\CustomCatalogInventoryModule\Model\StockRegistry::updateStockItemBySku`, example:

1. Create empty plugin class, `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistryPlugin`
2. Add to [`di.xml`](https://gist.github.com/aohorodnyk/1f8a214aa389b0d5f836), [example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7e6b1c6/app/code/Magento/Downloadable/etc/di.xml#L14-L16)
3. Add to plugin class method with suffix+original name, examples: [beforeUpdateStockItemBySku](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/adb5130/app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Order/Plugin/Authentication.php#L43-L50), [afterUpdateStockItemBySku](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/a9e5897/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/MessageBox.php#L89-L99), [aroundUpdateStockItemBySku](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/a9e5897/app/code/Magento/Downloadable/Model/Product/CartConfiguration/Plugin/Downloadable.php#L23-L32)

Successful, your plugin created.